# Nonabelian group of six elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is an example of a six-element group that is not abelian?

I can't think of any. It is very possible that I am overthinking this. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with permutation groups?

Comment: I copied "six-element group that is not abelian" into Google search; the first link answered the question. -1 for lack of research.

Answer (score 6):

The symmetric group, $S_3$, on the vertices of an equilateral triangle is non-abelian.  It is generated by a 120 degree counterclockwise rotation and a reflection over the perpendicular bisector of one of the sides.  As you can check, it is a non-abelian group with six elements since the reflection and rotation do not commute.

Answer (score 2):

In general,

> $\{e, a,b,b^2,ab,ab^2\}$

is a six-element **non-abelian** group, isomorphic to $S_3$, when $ba=ab^2$, where $a$ is an element of order $2$, $b$ an element of order $3$, and $e$ the identity element.

What's remarkable is that this very same set of elements can be used to represent a six-element **abelian** group, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$, when $ba=ab$ (in lieu of $ba=ab^2$).

And $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $S_3$ are, up to isomorphism, the only possible six-element groups!